# Inherit from html5 canvas class

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'd like to define my custom Canvas2D class in Javascript which inhertis from the native html5 canvas object. I'm trying to do it with a prototypal inheritence rather than the classic way like so:

```
function Canvas2D(){
    var parent = document.createElement("canvas");

    var child = Object.create(parent);        
    child.getContext = function(){
        return parent.getContext('2d');
    };
    return child;
}
```

So I can create and work with an object instance this way

```
var canvas = new Canvas2D();
var context = canvas.getContext();
```

But when I try to get the html5 native's `width` property like so:

```
var width = canvas.width;
```

my browser throws a `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` exception. Shouldn't this property get inherited too? I suppose this issues relates to some "get or set" restrictions or is some sort of access modifier's restriction for the properties in html5 native's canvas object.

Also when I try to call `drawImage` with an instance of my custom canvas as argument:

```
canvas.getContext().drawImage(new Canvas2D(), 300, 150);
```

the browser throws another exception - `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'`

In other words the browser complains about the type of Canvas2D object which I passed to drawImage method, though my canvas is of type HTMLCanvasElement! We can easily check this out with the following line:

```
console.log(new Canvas2D() instanceof HTMLCanvasElement);
```

In my browser prints out `true`.

So my questions are:

1) Can someone explain the reason behind the wrong behaviour of 'width' property and how can I work it around?

2) How can I force drawImage to recognise my class as HTMLCanvasElement, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably will not. One thing which may worth mentioning is that `HTMLCanvasElement` (and the other HTMLXY-s too) is an interface, which means the actual implementation may have details that simply do not appear on the JavaScript level. Like a canvas in particular has a backing buffer for sure, which you do not see at all. So the expected success of making a copy of it is at least questionable.

Trying a simple pair of

```js
console.log(document.createElement("canvas").width);
console.log(Object.create(document.createElement("canvas")).width);
```

already shows that it simply can not create a real `HTMLCanvasElement`. In fact, [`Object.create()`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.3.5) does not even try that hard:

> 1. If Type(O) is not Object or Null throw a TypeError exception.
> 2. Let obj be the result of creating a new object as if by the expression new Object() where Object is the standard built-in constructor with that name
> 3. Set the [[Prototype]] internal property of obj to O.
> 4. If the argument Properties is present and not undefined, add own properties to obj as if by calling the standard built-in function Object.defineProperties with arguments obj and Properties.
> 5. Return obj.

[`new Object()`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.2) tries a bit harder, it specifies that ***host objects*** (what HTMLXY-s are) are taken into account too:

> 1.a.i If the value is a native ECMAScript object, do not create a new object but simply return value.
>   1.a.ii If the value is a host object, then actions are taken and a result is returned in an implementation-dependent manner that may depend on the host object.

Testing your code with `new Object`:

```js
function Canvas2D(){
    var parent = document.createElement("canvas");

    var child = new Object(parent);        
    child.getContext = function(){
        return parent.getContext('2d');
    };
    console.log(parent===child);
    return child;
}

var cnv=new Canvas2D();
console.log(cnv.width);
var ctx=cnv.getContext();
```

It gets the proper `width` (defaults to 300), but there is something fishy with that "copy" (see the check for `child===parent`, resulting in true, hinting that no new object has been created, and the infinite recursion of `getContext` -at least in Chrome- suggests the same). Here and now I could not tell if it is 1.a.i (which should not be the case, a canvas or HTMLCanvasElement is not part of ECMA/JavaScript), or 1.a.ii (implementation-dependent behaviour when encountering a host object), but it does not work for sure. And it is not expected to: as mentioned at the beginning, the JavaScript-level "copy constructor" can not know about browser-level details of the actual implementing object.

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed answer! I consider that it's not possible to inherit from HTMLCanvasElement anyway.

Comment: @0xC0DEGURU I think it is not possible