# `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor.` when extending HTMLSpanElement

Tags: javascript, web-component

I am getting an `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor.` for a basically empty constructor:

```js
export class Citation extends HTMLSpanElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

A comment in this [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62743456/6662425) claimed that

> I encountered the same error with Web Components but only on Safari (not Firefox). Cause was that I did a class UserAvatar extends HTMLSpanElement (rather than HTMLElement)

This made me try out `HTMLElement` and this in fact removed the error. So now I am wondering. What HTML elements can I extend? Why can I not extend the span element? There are a couple of similar questions: [Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor when extending HTMLButtonElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42119743/uncaught-typeerror-illegal-constructor-when-extending-htmlbuttonelement), [How to create new instance of an extended class of custom elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39986046/how-to-create-new-instance-of-an-extended-class-of-custom-elements). But they are a bit older and in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39988275/6662425) it is claimed that this should now work since october 2018. I am using an up to date firefox browser so I am confused...

Anybody know whats going on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inherit from html5 canvas class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49464921/inherit-from-html5-canvas-class)

Comment: You can try some things, but it will unlikely work. Just like in case of canvas, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSpanElement starts as *The HTMLSpanElement **interface** represents* - so, it's an interface only, not the complete element. That's why an attempt on extending it usually fails.

Comment: Note that for 6 years now Apple has stated they will not implement _Customized Built-In Elements_ Because they do not comply to the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://stackify.com/solid-design-liskov-substitution-principle) Only _Autonomous Custom Elements_ ``extend HTMLElement`` are suported in Safari.

Comment: okay this answerw why the `HTMLSpanElement` does not work. Is there a list of html elements somewhere that is safe to extend? I mean the button example is in virtually every tutorial so I assume that it is desired that you extend more advanced elements if applicable

Comment: Documentation sucks (sometimes) That ``button`` example should be removed from the docs. If you want to support Safari (and not use Polyfills) you can not extend any _Built In_ Elements. Stick to _Autonomous Elements_, ``extend HTMLElement``

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman so avoid using `<cite is='paren-cite'` and instead use `<paren-cite` ? Or use polyfills (if I understood correctly what polyfills are)

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman ohh Autonomous Custom Element refers to whether it extends something not whether it is a stand-alone thing. I confused that with the thing above

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: The "is" debate goes all the way back to 2016: https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/509

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web Components : extending native elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56619025/web-components-extending-native-elements)

Comment: Now I am confused. There are basically 4 ways to do things: `is=` or not and extending `HTMLElement` or something more advanced e.g. `HTMLButtonElement` and those two things seem to be independent so I could mix and match to get 4 different ways. But there are only two labels: *Autonomous Custom Element* and *Customized Built-in Element*. That is fewer labels than options...

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman sorry forgot the tag (thank you for the help btw)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 2 types of Custom Elements [MDN: Using Custom Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements)

- **Autonomous Custom Elements**: `extend HTMLElement`
- **Customized Built-In Elements** `extend HTML<any>Element`
  [Polyfill](https://github.com/WebReflection/built-in-element) required for Safari
  because Apple doesn't want to implement this type of elements.
  For a good reason; [read the very long debate](https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/509)  (going back to 2016)

#### General advice

Stick to **autonomous** elements, unles you know what you are doing.

---

**One registry to rule them all**

(for now) There is only **one** registry so your **Customized element** is registered as `fancy-button`;
That means you can not mix the 2 types, with the same element name.

## Update

Dont use the 3rd parameter for Autonomous Elements (extending HTMLElement)

You can't mix settings:

```html
<script>
  class BaseClass extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      console.log("I AM ", this.nodeName);
    }
  }
  customElements.define('el-1', class extends BaseClass {});
  customElements.define('el-2', class extends BaseClass {}, {
    extends: "ul"
  });

</script>

<el-1></el-1>

<!-- doesn't do anything -->
<el-2></el-2>

<!-- throws "TypeError: Illegal constructor." -->
<ul is="el-2"></ul>
```

Comment: Does `class Citation extends HTMLElement` and then `customElements.define('my-cite', Citation, { extends: 'cite' });` count as an Autonomous Custom Element?

Comment: Nope, won't work. Run added code example

Comment: Actually it does work for `abstract class Citation extends HTMLElement` and `customElements.define('my-cite', ParenCitation, { extends: 'cite'});`

Comment: I edited your post to demonstrate - you can ignore that