# TypeError: Illegal constructor for CSSStyleSheet in Safari

Tags: node.js, webpack, safari

I am making a JS app in NodeJS and building it with Webpack.

I use Web Components mainly and have multiple components like this:

```
import style from "./inboxScreen.css" assert { type: "css" };

export class InboxScreen extends HTMLELement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" })

    this.shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets.push(style);

    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
    `;
  }
}

customElements.define("inbox-screen", InboxScreen);
```

The app works fine in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge but safari gives me a Type Error; Illegal constructor

It is all minified gibberish to me, but the error line is this:

```
  r.push([e.id, ":host {\n  width: 100%;\n\n  font-size: 14px;\n  color: grey;\n}\n\n.pending {\n  color: orange;\n}\n\n.total {\n  color: green;\n}\n\n.normal-state {\n  display: none;\n}\n\n.normal-state.active {\n  display: block;\n}\n\n.retrieval-state {\n  display: none;\n}\n\n.retrieval-state.active {\n  display: block;\n  animation: flash 2s infinite alternate;\n}\n\n@keyframes flash {\n  0% {\n    color: grey;\n  }\n  50% {\n    color: white;\n  }\n  100% {\n    color: grey;\n  }\n}\n\n.polling-state {\n  display: none;\n}\n\n.polling-state.active {\n  display: flex;\n}\n", ""]);
var o = new CSSStyleSheet;
o.replaceSync(r.toString()); // illegal constructor
```

My webpack config rules is like this:

```
    rules: [
      {
        assert: { type: "css" },
        loader: "css-loader",
        options: {
          exportType: "css-style-sheet",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
```

I have read that safari doesnt support the assert { type: "css" }; syntax, but is there a way to make this work, perhaps in the webpack config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the answer to your problem: [`Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor.` when extending HTMLSpanElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71901055/uncaught-typeerror-illegal-constructor-when-extending-htmlspanelement).

It has nothing to do with CSS, this is JS runtime problem. You need to add a polyfill, cause Apple being Apple, don't want to add full support for `HTMLElement`.

> **NOTE!** The polyfill project the original answer points to has moved to another repository. [Here is the link](https://github.com/ungap/custom-elements#readme).

**=== EDIT ===**

The answer above isn't quite correct. It was `CSSStyleSheet` that caused the error, not `CustomComponent`. [Link to polyfill](https://github.com/calebdwilliams/construct-style-sheets) for `CSSStyleSheet`.

Comment: But I am just extending HTMLElement. I am not extending custom elements, so there should be no problem??

Comment: My answer is somewhat misleading. `customElements.define`- you're using CustomElements. Try to add the polifyll and see what happens.

Comment: I put 
<script src="//unpkg.com/@ungap/custom-elements"></script>
in my head and nothing changed

Comment: I think I got it. What version of Safari do you use? Apply didn't support `CSSStyleSheet` till very recently (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet#browser_compatibility).

Comment: My new theory that you need a polifyll for `CSSStyleSheet:` https://github.com/calebdwilliams/construct-style-sheets

Comment: WOW, that worked, thank you so much. ALL PRAISE BOGDAN GISHKA, ULTIMATE GENIUS OF STACK OVERFLOW!!! THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: You're welcome))) Sorry, it took several tries. I somehow didn't notice `var o = new CSSStyleSheet;` line and concentrated on `HTMLElement` class instead.